# Connection Error , there was a networking error in the connection to "url"

Tags: java, json, codenameone

[OutPut Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQaSw.png)
[image: CONSOLE Output]

im trying to make an addAction , the method is working just fine on symfony web app and i get the data inserted , but im getting this error on my project when running it . and im wondering what can i do to recognize the error

> Connection Error , there was a networking error in the connection to http://localhost/KiddoEsprit/web/app_dev.php/ajoutermobile/aaaaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbbb/

```
public void ajouterReclamation(Reclamation r){
        ConnectionRequest con = new ConnectionRequest();
        String Url = "http://localhost/KiddoEsprit/web/app_dev.php/ajoutermobile/" +r.getTitre()+ "/" + r.getContenu()  ;
    con.setUrl(Url);

    con.addResponseListener((l) -> {
        String str = new String(con.getResponseData());
        System.out.println(str);

    });
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(con);

    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have a server on port 80 of your local machine. Usually these servers run on port 8080. Also you should point it to a server accessible from the cloud as when you're running on a device its localhost would be the phone itself which won't run the server

Comment: @ShaiAlmog  thank you for your time , there was no problem for port im using as its running good ,  the console output gave me html code , i added the picture in the post , as it says no route for "POST /ajoutermobile/.... " which is weird cause i dunno where the method post came from , i didn't get this error on my symfony app which in settings accepts all methods (post,get,..)

Comment: @ShaiAlmog the error was fixed when i started sending the object in a request instead of normal values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is fixed when i started sending the object in a request

```
String Url = "http://localhost/KiddoEsprit/web/app_dev.php/ajoutermobile?titre=" + r.getTitre()+ "&contenu=" + r.getContenu()  ;
```

and changed a few code lines on my symfony app